# error when trying to run an overloaded function with float parameters.

Tags: c++, function, c++11, overloading

I am trying to create a simple (absolute) function in c++, I have created two functions with the same name one that takes an integer and returns an integer and one that takes a float and returns a float but every time I try to run the code I receive this error:

**"error: call of overloaded 'absolute(double)' is ambiguous"**

I tried changing the input parameters of the second function so that it takes a double and returns a float and the code ran perfectly, I'd like to know why the code won't run when the parameters and return type are **both** set to float, thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int absolute(int x){
if (x<0){
    x=-x;
}
    return x;
}
float absolute (float x)
{
    if (x<0){
        x=-x;
    }
    return x;
}





int main( )
{
    cout << absolute(3.5);

}
```

Comment: It's better to use `double` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the literal `3.5` is `double`, not `float`.

Choosing either of the overloads would require a conversion. Hence the ambiguity.

You can use `3.5f` to make it a `float` literal.

```
cout << absolute(3.5f);
```

---

A better solution, IMO, would be to use a function template.

```
template <typename T>
T absolute(T x)
{
   return (x < 0 ? -x : x);
}
```

Comment: Or provide an overload for `double`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, or a function template.

Comment: @R Sahu Sure, that's one way to provide the overload.

Answer (score 1):

Read that error message again. Notice how it says ***`double`*** as the argument type it want to use.

That's because floating point constants like `3.5` are of type `double`. And the compiler don't know if it should convert the `double` value to an `int` or a `float`, thereby giving you the error.

If you want to call the `float` overload, use `3.5f` to make it a `float` value. Or change your overload to use type `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: thanks alot, I thought any number with a decimal point was considered a float

Answer (score 1):

you write that 3.5 is a float this value is not a float it is a double.